# Examining code in android take long time

Tags: android, eclipse

how to examining code in android, i'm using eclipse Juno
when I try to checking simple code ( 1 line coding like)

```
Log.d("check", "1234567890".substring(5,7);
```

in Eclipse, I have to compile, build, upload and installing to emulator that spent some minute.....

is there any trick to figure it out faster?

in visual basic, was have quick view window to check or examining syntact.
Is it able for eclipse examining code without building and compiling to emulator or device..?
thanks for advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Switch to Android Studio.
2. Switch to gradle.
3. Set gradle version to 2.0 or higher.
4. Enjoy the instant run option.

And yeah, both AndroidStuido and Intellij Idea do code inspections without having to re-build your app.

Comment: Nice, good one Solution, thanks @Dogcat... i will use your solution at last.. but, for now. what if I'm doing something(in the midle) with eclipse.. wait for another trick nor choose this as a solved solution